# how to store the name of the container in an array

Tags: flutter

hi i am new to flutter can anyone tell me how to save the preferences in an array
what are the methods used in storing the value

```
class PrefPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PrefPageState createState() => _PrefPageState();
}

class _PrefPageState extends State<PrefPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 30, 10),
        height: 80,
        child: Spring.bubbleButton(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
          },
          child: Text(
            "",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        leadingWidth: 0,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        title: Text(
          "Swoken",
          style: GoogleFonts.niconne(
            textStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                " What are your",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
              ),
              Text(
                " Interests ?",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              GridView.count(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                childAspectRatio: 2.3,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: List.generate(
                  intr.length,
                  (index) {
                    return PrefCont(
                      child: AutoSizeText(
                        intr[index]["icon"] + "  " + intr[index]["title"],
                        minFontSize: 16,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class PrefCont extends StatefulWidget {
  PrefCont({this.child});
  final child;

  @override
  _PrefContState createState() => _PrefContState();
}

class _PrefContState extends State<PrefCont> {
  List<String> sel = [];
  bool isSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var themeId = DynamicTheme.of(context)!.themeId;
    var kContColor = Color(0Xfff6f6f6);

    themeId == 0
        ? kContColor = Color(0Xfff6f6f6)
        : kContColor = Color(0xff272727);
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          isSelected = !isSelected;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isSelected ? kContInactColor : kContColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: What are the preferences you want to put in an array ? Where would you like to use it ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X1NvsE8z84aFO6EFeB7HCEsDg0tHsXfG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i have uploaded the layout pls check

Comment: It requires an authorization, put it a available with link. And it doesnt answer my question :)

Comment: now changed pls check

Comment: i need to store the title of the container

Comment: i have created a loop so that it creates container based on the data in a list provided how to store the users selection

Answer (score 0):

First you need to modelize your elements as objects then, you need to create a data set containing all of your tiles:

```
class PreferencesData {
    final String name;
    final String assetName;
    PreferencesData({required this.name, required this.assetName});
}

list _dataSet = [
   PreferencesData(name: "Football", assetName: "/assets/icons/football.png"),
   PreferencesData(name: "Food", assetName: "/assets/icons/food.png"),
   ...
];
```

Now that you have all your objects in a dataset you can use it in your grid to display them correctly:

```
children: [for (PreferencesData pref in _dataSet)
               PrefCont(...) // access your data with pref.name
          ]
```

Comment: i have already done this part my question is if the user selects a item the container will turn blue after selecting i have to store the value in an array how to do it

Comment: dont you already have it with the `bool selected` inside your PrefCont widget ????

Comment: yes the thing is if i select one container all the container changes color